# Turn these haskell Int lists into a different one

Tags: haskell, list

I have the following Int lists:

```
t1 = [1000, 1001, 1002, 1003, 1004]
t2 = [2000, 2001, 2002]
t3 = [3000, 3001, 3002, 3003]
```

The lists size are variable, they are not just 3 like in this example. They can have 1 element or many more. Then I have this:

```
tAll = [t1, t2, t3]
```

I need a function that "turns" **tAll** into something like this:

```
[[1, 1000, 2000, 3000],
[2, 1001, 2001, 3001],
[3, 1002, 2002, 3002],
[4, 1003, 0, 3003], 
[5, 1004, 0, 0]]
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

**EDIT:**
I'm sorry, I posted this in a hurry and it was not exactly what I wanted. I updated the code above...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this is the Haskell beginner's way to write it, but since it's doing explicit recursion there is probably a better way. :-)

```
head0 [] = 0
head0 xs = head xs

tail0 [] = []
tail0 xs = tail xs

nreorder n ts
  | all null ts = []
  | otherwise   = (n : map head0 ts) : nreorder (n+1) (map tail0 ts)
```

And `nreorder 1 tAll` prints the list you want. You can avoid those indices by doing the following instead:

```
reorder ts
  | all null ts = []
  | otherwise   = (map head0 ts) : reorder (map tail0 ts)
```

so that `reorder tAll = [[1000,2000,3000],[1001,2001,3001],[1002,2002,3002],[1003,0,3003],[1004,0,0]]`, and (slightly cleaned up thanks to mattiast):

```
nreorder ts = zipWith (:) [1..] (reorder tAll)
```

so that `nreorder tAll` prints the list you want.

Comment: I find it confusing... Isn't there a way to do it without the extra head/tail functions and/or without the "all null ts = []" thing?

Comment: The extra head/tail functions are the easiest way to express what you want to do with an empty list.  Get used to auxiliary functions if you want to use Haskell.

The "all null ts" thing is useful for handling an arbitrary number of input lists, instead of exactly 2, 3 or 42 lists...

Comment: The "all null ts" means whether "all the lists in ts are empty". Think of what you need to do at the last steps, where after "nreorder 4 [[1003,1004],[],[3003]]", and "nreorder 5 [[1004],[],[]]" it comes to "nreorder 6 [[],[],[]]".

Comment: And er, you shouldn't be reading it as "all null ts = []" -- maybe you need to get familiar with the guard syntax? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guard_%28computing%29

Answer (score 9):

Here is a one-liner for you, if you're still interested:

```
zipWith (:) [1..] $ take (maximum $ map length tAll) 
                         (transpose (map (++repeat 0) tAll))
```

edit: OK, it's better to write it with two lines :)

Comment: Very nice, +1. This is the best solution! Contrary to what I said in my previous comment, this is linear in both the length of each list and the number of lists :-)

Answer (score 2):

smells like homework, so I won't give code, but some hints:
  -  the length of the resulting lists are all the same, which is the max of the lists. Find that max and pad all the other lists with zeroes (using laziness you can pad all the lists with an infinite list of zeroes).
  - get an intermediate version working that just prints the first column of your eventual answer...
  - when you have that working, get the 2nd column.... and the rest should be gravy.

Edit: Comments indicate that it's not homework, so:

```
list = [[1000, 1001, 1002, 1003, 1004],[2000, 2001, 2002],[3000, 3001, 3002, 3003]]
```

main = do mapM_ (putStrLn.show) (rotate list)
rotate list = [(i+1):map (!!i) paddedlist | i<-[0..(len-1)] ]
 where len = maximum $ map length list
       paddedlist = map (++repeat 0) list

Comment: Oops, I hope I didn't give away a homework answer... But given that his first version of the question was something entirely different, and his previous questions seem to have been about Html stuff, this is more likely to be a problem from "real life".

Comment: This is still about the Html stuff, I just made a generic example to be easier to understand and I'll adapt it later. Actually this is for a project I have to turn in tomorrow, but this problem in particular is something I want to do, it's not part of any requested feature.

Comment: Nice. How much time does it take, BTW? It seems (because of the !! and ++) that something is quadratic where it can be linear, but I'm not really sure how to reason in the face of lazy evaluation.

Comment: Is (!!) linear or constant time? I can see it being linear, stepping thru the list, but, with boxing, it could be const-just mult to get the offset. At any rate, some quick timings show rotate 5 times faster than nreorder (5sec vs 1sec on (take 10e5 list) under ghc 6.8.2). I might profile it.

Comment: (!!) is linear. But I don't know if ghc can figure out all the successive (!!)s in total linear time. And er... do you mean "slower"? It seems that rotate is linear in the number of lists but quadratic in the lengths: O(mn^2) for m lists of length n, while nreorder is O(mn). Because of (++) I guess.

Answer (score 1):

`zip3` will turn the 3 lists into a single list of triples.  If you want length-three lists instead, you can use `zipWith3 (\a b c -> [a,b,c])`

If you want something different in detail (as in your updated request), you'll have to roll your own.  I'd say, put your termination condition first, then deal with the general case.  You should have two auxiliary functions -- one to fix the values the way you want (e.g., "head_or_zero"), and one to handle input lists that have terminated (e.g., "tail_or_nil"):

```
fix _ [] [] [] = []
fix i as bs cs = [i, hoz as, hoz bs, hoz cs]:fix (i+1) (ton as) (ton bs) (ton cs) where
    hoz [] = 0
    hoz x:xs = x
    ton [] = []
    ton x:xs = xs
```